# Высокая скорость объекта и соприкосновение с другими объектами

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

У меня есть рыцарь с мечом. Он машет им(мечом) со скоростью примерно 0.1 сек(делал удар с помощью анимации.Выставлял скорость 80).
   Если меч попадает по противнику, то у противника вычитаются хп. Но из-за того, что скорость высокая, бывает так, что OnTriggerEnter не срабатывает. На сколько я понимаю, что между кадрами меч проходит сквозь противника. Как это исправить?

На противниках у меня стоит ригидбоди и скрипт. Если противник соприкасается с мечом, то он умирает.
  Пробовал на ригидбоди ставить continuous,не помогает, да и вроде как после этого производительность упала.
  Так же пробовал вместо OnTriggerEnter использовать RayCast.Он тоже работает плохо. Т.к. у меня у некоторых врагов жизней на два удара. С рейкастом их убивает с одного. Или в двух. Или с 3х. Как пойдет в общем.
Вот кусок кода, не знаю зачем. Но может подскажете что-то.

```
  void Update () {
    RaycastHit objectHit;
    Vector3 fwd = lightSaber.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
    Debug.DrawRay(lightSaber.transform.position, fwd * lightsaberLength, Color.green);
    if (Physics.Raycast(lightSaber.transform.position, fwd, out objectHit, lightsaberLength))
    {
        //do something if hit object ie
        if (objectHit.transform.tag == "Big Ninja")
        {
            bigNinja.GetComponent<bigNinjaHealth>().BigNinjaHurt();
            Debug.Log("Light_saber kill");
        }

        if (objectHit.transform.tag == "weak Ninja")
        {
            weakEnemy.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().weakNinjaHurt();
            Debug.Log("Light_saber kill");
        }
        if (objectHit.transform.tag == "Coins")
        {
            objectHit.transform.GetComponent<Coins>().addCoins();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется надо сделать некий класс, предок для всех скилов. Удар мечом - тоже своего рода скил. Так вот у этого класса будут полz: радиус действия. поражения, минимальная и  максимальная дистанция на которой скил действует, `offset` - крайняя точка скила, когда происходит удар (то есть относительно анимации) и пр.. есть анимация например 2 сек, точка удара в 1.1сек - 66кадров..... собственно этот скил висит на персонаже, нажимается кнопка удара, и когда проходят эти 66 кадров смотрится: противник на расстоянии поражения и его радиусе? Если да - отнимаем ему `HP`. И никакие rigidbody не нужны

Answer (score 0):

В общем, вроде решил проблему с использованием лайнкаста. Сделал вдоль меча два лайнкаста, что бы ну никак враги не могли пройти мимо них. Пока, вроде, все работает.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class lineCast : MonoBehaviour {
public Transform target;
public GameObject empty = null;



// Use this for initialization

void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    RaycastHit hit;
    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, target.position);
    if (Physics.Linecast(transform.position, target.position,out hit))
    {

            if (hit.collider.tag == "weak Ninja")
            {

                hit.collider.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().weakNinjaHurt();

            }
```

}
}